# This is my continual error: Error in interest_over_time(widget, comparison_item, tz) : Status code was not 200. Returned status code:429

Tags: r, google-trends, gtrendsr

I am currently trying to use gtrendsR but nothing will plot.

So far, this is what my code looks like:

```
trend <- gtrends("women in stem",
                 gprop = 'web',
                 geo = 'US',
                 time = "today+5-y",
                 onlyInterest = TRUE)

Sys.sleep(1)

plot(trend)
```

I also tried with an API key

```
trend <- gtrends("women in stem",
                 gprop = 'web',
                 geo = 'US',
                 time = "today+5-y",
                 onlyInterest = TRUE,
                 gkey = "YOUR_API_KEY")
```

I have tried the code without the sys.sleep.
I have even tried basic gtrends code like gtrends(c("NHL", "NFL"), time = "now 1-H") and it gives me the same error.
I tried them hours apart and shutting down R Studio but nothing seems to work. Is it my R Studio or is something else the matter?
I want a graph of the google trends of the term "women in stem" over the past five years.

Thank you!

Comment: A 429 HTTP status code indicates too many requests originating from your IP address within a given time, so Google is rate limiting your attempts to scrape Google Trends data. You can try increasing the amount of time between requests with `Sys.sleep()`, passing a username and password to `setHandleParameters()`, or the `gtrends_with_backoff()` function from the [`trendecon` package](https://github.com/trendecon/trendecon/blob/master/R/gtrends_with_backoff.R) but this seems to be an [open and known issue](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/issues/431) due to changes made by Google.